# Video Streaming and recording website

Tags: video-streaming

I need to create a website that has to have the ability to live-stream video from a connected camera and microphone as well as store it somewhere (on the web server ? or somewhere else) so that people who missed it, can watch it later.

That would you recommend me to do ?

Comment: Depends upon your development background.

Comment: I recommend: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @Umair I can handle most language if you mean that. The site is built in php so far, but I only need to make this recording and streaming thing working.